# How does accordion collapse doesn't toggle on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

The images are like this
1. On page load.[image: On page laod, collapseTwos is active]
2. When click on collapseTwos button i.e (next) ,the collapseTwos doesn't toggle.[image: collapseTwos doesn't toggle]

The live example is here , this works fine on it ,but in asp page it doesn't
Follow the link

```
http://www.bootply.com/DcMZxTPDI8#
```

All file are included ,this code i'm working in masterpage child.The CollapseTwos always reamin untoggle on button click.This problem occurs on every page load,then after it works.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <!-- <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwos"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list">
                        </span> </a> -->
                        META DATA
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwos" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <a id="btn2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThrees"
                                            class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-success">Next</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- _____________________________________________________________-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <!--   <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThrees"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list">
                        </span> </a>-->
                        META DATA
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThrees" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <a id="btn3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFours"
                                            class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-success">Next</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <!-- <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFours"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a>-->META DATA
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFours" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <a id="btn4" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwos"
                                            class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-success">Next</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".btn4").click(function () {
           $("#collapseFours").collapse('toggle');
       });
       $(".btn2").click(function () {
           $("#collapseTwos").collapse('toggle');
       });
       $(".btn3").click(function () {
           $("#collapseThrees").collapse('toggle');
       });

   });
</script>
```

All js files are included in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied and pasted your code it works on my machine. And why did you comment those anchor tags? Anyways, i uncommented those and it works mate.

Comment: Also check if your loading jquery then bootstrap in that order

Comment: i dont those anchor tags to as link purpose ,instead of that i use buttons for those to collapse. Your suggestion works, but i want it perform function  on button click,all my jquery are fine working. Thnks for your suggestion . @HastaPasta